# Tesseract and tiff format - spp not in set {1,3}

Tags: tesseract

While trying to run this command:

```
tesseract bond111.tif bond111 batch.nochop makebox
```

I get the next error

```
Error in pixReadFromTiffStream: spp not in set {1,3}
Error in pixReadStreamTiff: pix not read
Error in pixReadTiff: pix not read
```

Assuming that `spp not in set` is the main error here, what does it mean?
 At first it had trouble because the bpp was higher than 24 so I reduced it using Gimp but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I see no reason for this question to be closed. The OP gives an explicit software command that they tried and the details on the error they received. Tesseract is a relatively active tag on SO and this is quite relevant to it. Many people (including myself) continue to find this page helpful. Working with Tesseract isn't the same as a lang like python, so questions will look a bit diff. But if Tesseract is accepted as a tag on SO then I see no reason why this question shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It probably means your TIFF image has an alpha channel and therefore the underlying Leptonica library used by Tesseract doesn't support it.  If you're using Imagemagick then be aware that operations such as `-draw` can cause alpha channels to be added.  If you're using `convert` in your workflow and want to remove the channel again immediately, flatten the image before writing by adding `-background white -flatten +matte` before the output filename, e.g.:

```
convert input.tiff -fill white -draw 'rectangle 10,10 20,20' -background white -flatten +matte output.tiff
```

Tesseract (well, Leptonica) accepts PNGs these days and is less picky about them, so it might be easier to migrate your workflow to PNG anyway.

Sources: magick-users [mailing list posting](http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2006-August/018215.html); tesseract-ocr [mailing list posting](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/msg/779e72f77e6e4706)

Comment: Interesting. This solution works for me, but only generates the last page of the input pdf I have.

Comment: Looks like the -flatten command reduces it to a single page. Removing that fixed everything for me.

Comment: Note that `+matte` is deprecated according to the docs. Use `-alpha Off` instead.

Comment: @fotNelton Thanks: it's the -alpha Off that did it for me. -flatten is definitely not helpful for a multipage scan

Comment: PNGs worked great for me.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: So far the current tesseract does NOT accept PNG as a single appended file.  Nor does tesseract accept a flattened tiff with the above options.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks for your post ZakW, you pointed me to the right direction.
Anyhow i also needed to set '-depth 8'. Quality was not good enough for OCR, whatever I tried.

What worked for me is this solution:

```
ghostscript -o document.tiff -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r720x720 -g6120x7920 -sCompression=lzw document.pdf
tesseract document.tiff document -l deu
vim document.txt
```

This way I got perfect text with Umlauts in german.

Comment: This approach is the only one which has successfully converted the content to a text file.  It makes no sense why the accepted answer is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Adjusting the conversion to the following line did help me.

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -depth 8 -background white -alpha Off output.tiff
```

Note that the other answers did not work for me since they use the deprecated `+matte` flag instead of `-alpha Off`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the command 'tiffinfo' provided by libtiff_tools to verify the TIFF format of your src image. A number of TIFF formats exist, with different values for Bits-per-pixel (bpp) and Samples-per-pixel (spp).

`Error in pixReadFromTiffStream: spp not in set {1,3,4}`

An 'spp' value of 2 is invalid for TIFF.

I solved the problem by saving directly to TIFF format from Gimp, instead of converting from .png to .tif using ImageMagick's 'convert'.

See also: [TIFF format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm)