# jTessBoxEditorFX - Cannot Handle 600dpi .png Files

Tags: tesseract

I have a pdf that I have converted to .png at 500dpi and 600dpi. (see below).  The 500dpi version works just fine with jTessBoxEditor.  But, the 600dpi one fails.  I have tried increasing the JVM heap size as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995680/tesseract-train-with-different-image-format-than-used-for-primary-ocr/38004617?noredirect=1#comment63487385_38004617).  Even the 600 dpi image is only 91KB.  Even when I set the JVM heap size quite large, by running jTessBoxEditor as:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/"  ## necessary to get latest java runtime environment because I am on a mac.
java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -jar jTessBoxEditorFX.jar
```

I still fail to be able to open the 600dpi version.  Instead, I get a very long set of errors in the terminal.  Some snippets of these are:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderBuf.validate(NGCanvas.java:213)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.initCanvas(NGCanvas.java:640)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:603)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)

...

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderBuf.validate(NGCanvas.java:213)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.initCanvas(NGCanvas.java:640)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderForcedContent(NGCanvas.java:624)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderForcedContent(NGGroup.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderForcedContent(NGGroup.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderForcedContent(NGGroup.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderForcedContent(NGGroup.java:198)

...

    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:330)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The 500dpi image is here:
[image: 500dpi png]

and the 600dpi image is here:
[image: 600dpi png]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing you did. Unless you need to deal with complex scripts, I suggest you use the non-JavaFX version.

Comment: @nguyenq Perfect, yes, the version 1.6 on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vietocr/files/jTessBoxEditor/) worked perfectly for 600 dpi .png files.  Thank you!  Do you want to move your comment to an answer to make it easier for others to find?  Thanks for so much work and help from you on these tools!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing you did. Unless you need to deal with complex scripts, I suggest you use the non-JavaFX version.